# What's the name of the style of 3-8 lowercase letters?

Tags: unix

If you go on GitHub, so many of the project names are 3-8 lowercase letters. So many directories of those projects are 3-8 lowercase letters.

In the base level directory of most unix OS's, the directories are 3-8 lowercase letters.

This occurs even if the directory's name is an abbreviation for something a bit longer, and occurs even at the expense of clarity. For example, for the longest time I had no clue what sbin, proc, var were.

I'm led to believe that this is a stylistic choice among programmers, because it looks cool or something (not making fun of it; it does look cool and adds a level of consistency to directory names).

Does anyone know of a name of this style?

Idk how to tag this, so I'm adding a unix tag.

Comment: not a clue what you mean lol

Comment: Interesting question.  I know that DOS, before a certain version, only allowed up to 8 characters for filename and directories.  Not sure about UNIX.

Comment: @L_Church He probably want to know if there is a way to qualify the "style" of naming mnt (mount) tmp (temporary) lib (library) bin (binary) and such.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen early Unix limited them to 14 chars as I remember.

Comment: some age old naming convention? it would need a bit of digging maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure how 'age old' this is. This style of naming is alive and well within the open source community

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix#Components ??? That's my best bet. Just know it's mad old.

Comment: The traditional unix username limit is 8 characters. Even now I'd expect occasional truncation of longer usernames when using traditional unix tools. That may be one reason some things have 8-letter names.